# combobox with data from several fields in access

Tags: ms-access

I have created a table with several columns and a related form. In that form, I have created a combobox to show the columns of the table in differents rows in combobox.

I have 3 fields in my table: product1, product2 and product3 for a same order I have named with a number. When I create the combobox, values show in 3 differents columns in the same row so I can just select the data from the first row and column. But what I need is the field's data displayed in different rows instead showing data in different columns.

I researched in forums, and I read It can be solved with a join query and selecting that in row source in combobox menu, but I have tried it and I got the same result. I don´t know what am I doing wrong. I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've tried in your solution attempts. This will make it much easier to understand your problem and more likely that it gets answered.

Comment: You need no _normalise your database_ (bing/google on this) to have the products in a subtable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I forgot to mention I have a query from another table with product's names. But It doesn´t work.

Comment: I tried to normalize my data base with access wizard, but It seems I have a too small database to divide it. Anyway, I tried it, but I can`t get the right table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pivot the results

this is an example of how to restructure using sub queries bad data designs

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT QualifierID  --    <--- this is a unique identifier
    , 
        (
            SELECT QualifierText 
            FROM [QDB].[dbo].[Qualifier] x
            -- this is how you tie the unique identifier and grab a specific element by itself
            -- also pay attention to how we're making it equal to q.QualifierID, 
            -- which is the alias to the table below
            WHERE QualifierID=q.QualifierID
        ) AS QualifierText 
    , 
        (
            SELECT [ExampleText] 
            FROM [QDB].[dbo].[Qualifier] x 
            -- this is how you tie the unique identifier and grab a specific element by itself
            -- also pay attention to how we're making it equal to q.QualifierID, 
            -- which is the alias to the table below
            WHERE QualifierID=q.QualifierID   
        ) AS ExampleText 
    , 
        (
            SELECT [WhenModified] 
            FROM [QDB].[dbo].[Qualifier] x 
            -- this is how you tie the unique identifier and grab a specific element by itself
            -- also pay attention to how we're making it equal to q.QualifierID, 
            -- which is the alias to the table below
            WHERE QualifierID=q.QualifierID 
        ) AS WhenModified 
    FROM [QDB].[dbo].[Qualifier] q  -- this is a table alias
) z -- this is the alias fo the subquery combining everything together.
```

Comment: Thanks, but, Its a little bit confusing to me (I'm a beginner) ¿Could you please explain a little bit how to do this? I tried to pivot the table with a cross tabulation query, but I couldn`t get the what I want. ¿How could I apply that code to my database?.

Comment: Could I use a code like this?                                                             
_italic_TRANSFORM Sum(Compras.Importe) AS SumaDeImporte
SELECT Compras.PG
FROM Compras
WHERE (((Compras.BU)='EPMV'))
GROUP BY Compras.PG
PIVOT Format([FechaCobro],"mmmm")_italic_

Comment: @Ruy see edited answer. You need to learn how to use subqueries and how you can relate outer queries to data elements in subqueries